# Numpy amin and amax alternative or algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I have to move an API from my server to AWS Lambda. Lambda has a size limit, i.e., 250 MB. I used numpy's [`amin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html) and [`amax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html) methods in my code, rest of numpy is useless for me. Is there any other alternative to numpy in my case or can anyone tell me the algorithm for `amin` and `amax` without getting the time complexity of `O(m+n)`? Thank you

Comment: If you sort your data I would be a simple lookup ^.^. Otherwise I don't see how you can get around the complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the Python built-in functions `max` and `min` not work for you?

```
>>> max([1, 2, 3])
3
>>> min([1, 2, 3])
1
```

For a 2D list you can use a comprehension:

```
>>> l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> [max(r) for r in l] # max by rows, or axis = 1
[3, 6, 9]
>>> [max(r) for r in zip(*l)] # max by cols, or axis = 0
[7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: No they don't because I need to get the minimum and maximum of every row and column in a list. amin and amax have an argument "axis" which does it for me automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm like 3 years late, but, tf.experimental.numpy.amin and amax